# Что такое "как" в этом предложении?

Tags: морфология

Что такое "как" в этом предложении?

**День как мгновение.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ПАС Лопатина**, указывая на случаи, когда тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, определяет слово "как" в таких предложениях как **сравнительную частицу**:
***Если сказуемое выражено оборотом со сравнительными частицами как, словно, что, точно, вроде как и др.: Жизнь как легенда; Небо словно раскинутый шатер; Брошка вроде как пчелка (Ч.); Лес точно сказка; Неделя что один день. Быстро проходит; Пруд как блестящая сталь (Фет). Не ставится тире и при как, вводящем сказуемое, лексически совпадающее с подлежащим: Льды как льды, пустыни как пустыни (Кав.); Деревня как деревня; Домик как домик — старенький, темный (Шукш.)*** (http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=52#pg52). 
Если Вас интересует синтаксическая роль КАК, то тут ничего особенного нет: это частица (я бы сказала СОЮЗ-ЧАСТИЦА), а потому в строгом смысле никаким членом предложения она не является. Частица входит в состав сказуемого "[есть] как мгновение". Частица КАК не заменяет здесь связку ЕСТЬ, у неё роль другая - внести значение сравнения.

Comment: Согласен, что оттенок сравнения здесь ощущается, но ведь  вопрос о том, ЧЕМ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ КАК В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ. Речь не о КАК в смысле части речи, о чем говорится в Вашем ответе, а о члене предложения

Comment: Благодарю Вас, вопрос и в самом деле можно понять двояко: что такое КАК в этом предложении? Если бы было "чем является", мой ответ был бы другим... Попробую дополнить. Спасибо ещё раз!

Answer (score 1):

Нечто подобное недавно обсуждалось. В данном предложении "как" является составной частью сказуемого. В ходе дискуссии некоторые участники предлагали считать "как"
 заменой глагола-связки "есть", и я с ними вполне согласен (День есть мгновение)

Comment: В этом случае утрачивается оттенок сравнения, а в исходном предложении он ведь чувствуется...